# Android Animation to load viewgroup / layout on drag/swipe the view(Button)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, window-managers, android-windowmanager

I need help on showing a layout(Screen) with animation on **WindowManager**

[image: Screen1: WindowManager having Button < while drag/ swipe the button viewgroup/ layout need to load on the screen which is visibility was gone previously. Like a notification bar, when we swipe from top to bottom it will be visible slowly from top to bottom same like here from Left to right]

[image: Animation while drag the button on WindowManager]

[image: After animation fill view will be displayed]

1. Screen1: WindowManager having Button **<** while drag/ swipe the button viewgroup/ layout need to load on the screen which is visibility was gone previously.

---

Like a notification bar, when we swipe from top to bottom it will be visible slowly from top to bottom same like here from Left to right

2. Screen 2:Animation while drag the button on WindowManager
3. Screen 3:After animation fill view will be displayed

Comment: so you need `android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper`